# Chrome extension + jQuery: How to get the element under the cursor when a context menu is opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension in typescript and i want to fetch the element that the user right clicked when opening the context menu.

I've tried using the `contextmenu` event, but that always semes to return the document root as the target.

```
$(document).contextmenu((eventObject: JQueryMouseEventObject) => {
    console.log(eventObject.target); // This always prints the root element
});
```

I've also tried using the `click` event, and that works just fine for left click but not for right click.

```
$(document).click((eventObject: JQueryMouseEventObject) => {
    console.log(eventObject.target); // left click is fine, right click is not
});
```

Lastly I've also tried using the `mousedown` event, same result as with click.

```
$(document).mousedown((eventObject: JQueryMouseEventObject) => {
    console.log(eventObject.target);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: might be an overkill but can you try document.elementFromPoint(); by getting the x and y

Comment: @JaromandaX did you even read the question?

Comment: not very well :p obviously!!! but non jQueery `document.addEventListener('contextmenu', e => console.log(e.target))` always prints the actual element that was right-clicked - hence why I suggested the `contextmenu` event - rather than using the jQueery `contextmenu` method - and the comment below suggests even jQuery can get it right sometimes

Comment: using jquery https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/0681reux/7/

Comment: Yeah, both the native DOM contextmenu handler and jQuery jsfiddle work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trickery i found out that the reason neither of my previous attempts were working were because i was running my test website with the `Toggle device toolbar` option of the inspector turned on. 
Turning it off resulted in all 3 different event triggers working as intended.

I ended up using the `contextmenu` event trigger for my project.

```
$(document).contextmenu((eventObject: JQueryMouseEventObject) => {
    console.log(eventObject.target); // This always prints the root element
});
```